# Three-way selector switch to push button switch

Tags: switches, switching, video

I have a 3-way video switcher which uses a selector switch, is it possible to change this to a momentary push button?

Project - I want to watch three video feeds from cameras on one screen. With this selector button it works, but I want to use an illuminated push button which will give me an idea which video to select.

[image]

Comment: "*Please bare with me*" is an invitation to undress together. Try, "Please bear with me" as in "to bear one another's burdens". Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: @Transistor well, it made me giggle. akshay, the answer is "yes, it can be done. What is your question?" By the way, the only thing you'd be keeping from that board is the connectors – you'll probably end up designing your own PCB, because video signals typically do not like free-flying unshielded cables. In that sense, you forgot to actually ask a question!

Comment: Didn't realized what i typed in hurry, @Marcus my question is how do i achieve this i have never designed PCB. I assume i can simply copy the one i have but again i am not 100% sure. So trying to understand where can i learn this or find more details.

Comment: That is a simple mechanical switch - no electronics involved, so it can't easily be modified to use pushbuttons.  A possible solution would be to use a hobby servo arranged to push and pull the existing mechanical switch - but you'd have to work out a way to control the servo...

Comment: since you are new to electronics, i have to ask this .... please describe what you think is a `momentary push button switch` .... how do you think that it operates? ..... it is quite possible that your information is different from reality

Comment: @jsotola i want use this switch for starting 1 min video, and then that push button will be back to normal. Now I have 3 camera input which I will be checking at a given time.  With current selector it's possible but not good looking design. As push button are fancy with light i want use those

Comment: It's not called push button. It's called radio button, like the switches on old radios or film editing decks etc. It is a dedicated mechanical module... and I don't think they are available nowadays. You will have to search in the electronics scrap market at your local big city. Otherwise you can try hacking an old tape deck switch assembly. Alternatively, it can be built with relays, as the answer below shows. The cheapest upgrade will probably be 1 switch per channel, and you operate two switches simultaneously with two hands (one hand switches off, other hand switches on).

Comment: Also, I think, rotary switches with 360 degree movement are available, but I haven't seen one with 3 poles

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could replace it with momentary switches but it's not simple. That is a 3 Pole 3 Throw switch. For a push button you would need at least three 3 pole Single Throw switches, one per input, preferably ones that are ganged together (so pressing one disconnects the other). And if its momentary you would have to hold the button in for it to work. Or you would need to replace the switches with analog control circuits to switch the inputs. Or a digital circuit with bus switch ICs and microcontroller.

It's so much easier to buy one that does what you want. There are super cheap ones with remote controls even!

Comment: could you please provide me any specific which i can buy, the one i have with selector switch for 3$, i found other too but its like 30$. So i didn't understood just by adding push button did it changed cost that much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution, using a diode matrix, push button switches and magnetic latch relays.

S1, S2 and S3 are momentary push buttons to select the required channel.

[image]

'NO' contacts of the relays K1, K2 & K3 are to be used to switch the channels.

Relays with gold plated contacts are a must if low level signals are to be switched.

Freewheeling diodes for the relay coils and LED indicators are not shown.

-Nandu.